# Allowing backspace in winforms input field

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm validating users input to accept only numbers

```
 private void txtEdition_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
    if ((int)e.KeyChar < 48 || e.KeyChar > 57)
        e.Handled = true;
 }
```

but this also disabling backspace in this input field. How can allow backspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && 
    !Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

[Char.IsNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isnumber.aspx), *Indicates whether a Unicode character is categorized as a number*
[Char.IsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18zw7440.aspx), *Indicates whether the specified Unicode character is categorized as a control character.*

However, this will not block copy/paste operations and thus you still need to validate the input using some kind of TryParse when you need the data typed in this textbox

Comment: It may also be worth setting the ContextMenu for the TextBox to be a new ContextMenu, this will stop the user from right clicking and pasting non-numeric characters.